# Laravel Dusk: how to add PageLoadStrategy='none'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I need my dusk test suite to wait until every single page is full loaded.

We received suggestion to "add PageLoadStrategy='none'"

... but where and how to add this in the context of Laravel 9 + Dusk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found:

```
tests/DuskTestCase.php
```

In `protected function driver()`, I modified `$options` for my specific use case

```
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(collect([
        $this->shouldStartMaximized() ? '--start-maximized' : '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--page-load-strategy=none'
    ])->unless($this->hasHeadlessDisabled(), function ($items) {
        return $items->merge([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--user-data-dir=C:/Chromedevsession',
            '--page-load-strategy=none',
            '--headless',
            '--aggressive-cache-discard',
            '--log-level=3', 
            '--silent'       
        ]);
    })->all());
```